# Android ListView with edit text row items get resized on orientation change

Tags: listview, android-edittext, android-orientation

Turning my Android phone from potrait to landscpe, results in all the list items in my list view are are getting resized. ListView is not refreshed correctly. The listview width is not fills parent on orientation change. I tried **configChanges:orientation** in manifest file for my activity, but still result is same.

Images are shown below:

potrait:

[image]

landscape:

[image]

The whole row is getting reized on orientation change.

Below mentioned the xml layout used:

```
 <LinearLayout

        a:id="@+id/web_watch_list_modifier_row_body"
        a:visibility="visible"
        a:gravity="center"
        a:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"
        a:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
            a:id="@+id/watch_list_name_text_box"
            a:layout_height="40dip"
            a:layout_width="0dip"
             a:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            a:maxLength="32"
            a:singleLine="true"
            a:layout_weight="40"/>


    <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/dragImageView"
            a:background="@drawable/drag_button_img"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Awaiting yours valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Start with changing the a:layout_width or the LinearLayout to "match_parent"
I'm not sure what layout_weight="40" achieves when other elements don't have a weight, try 1.

I would try a RelativeLayout instead, like this (didn't check the xml correctness):

```
<RelativeLayout
        a:id="@+id/web_watch_list_modifier_row_body"
        a:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <EditText
            a:id="@+id/watch_list_name_text_box"
            a:layout_height="40dip"
            a:layout_width="0dip"
            a:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            a:maxLength="32"
            a:singleLine="true"
            a:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            />


    <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/dragImageView"
            a:background="@drawable/drag_button_img"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"
            a:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            a:layout_toLeftOf="@id/watch_list_name_text_box" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you don't declare android:configChanges then your activity is restarted when you change orientation, you don't want that if all you need is the layout to fit the new orientation.

Important,If your target version is higher then 13 then you need to declare also "screenSize"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

if this still doesn't work try overrriding onConfigurationChanged() and there invalidating the ListView

Answer (score 0):

Every time you rotate your device the activity restarts.. may be that is the reason EditText resizes...

Try add this in your manifest file,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

You can check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html as well.